# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, constraints

Intento crear un par de tablas en MySQL, este es la sentencia para crear la primera:

```
----- Creamos la Tabla de Usuarios del Sistema

Create table if not exists USUARIO
(
ID_USUARIO     BIGINT UNSIGNED not null auto_increment comment 'Id de la Tabla de Usuarios',
FICHA_LARGA    varchar(10)     not null                comment 'Representa el numero del usuario',
FICHA_CORTA    varchar(10)     not null                comment 'Representa el numero del usuario',
NOMBRE         varchar(50)     not null                comment 'Nombre Completo del Usuario',
CORREO         varchar(50)     not null                comment 'Correo de notificacion del usuario',
USUARIO_ACTIVO char(1)         not null default 'Y'    comment 'Bandera que indica si el usuario esta activo',
Primary Key(ID_USUARIO)
);
```

Sin embargo al intentar crear la siguiente tabla me genera el error:

> (Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint).

```
----- Creamos la Tabla con la Cabecera de Venta del Sistema

Create table if not exists CABECERA_VENTA
(
ID_CABECERA_VENTA  Bigint UNSIGNED not null auto_increment            comment 'Id de la Tabla de Cabecera de Ventas',
ID_USUARIO         Bigint          not null                           comment 'Id del Usuario que realiza la compra',
FECHA_CREADO       Datetime        not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP comment 'Fecha y Hora de Venta',
MONTO_TOTAL        Decimal         not null                           comment 'Monto Total de la Venta Realizada',
PROCESADA          Char(1)         not null default 'N'               comment 'Bandera para indicar si la Venta ya fue procesada en un Corte',
FECHA_CORTE        Date                     default null              comment 'Fecha Corte en la que fue incorporada la Venta',
Primary Key(ID_CABECERA_VENTA),
Constraint ID_USUARIO
Foreign Key(ID_USUARIO) 
References USUARIO(ID_USUARIO)
);
```

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema es un detalle bastante simple, puedes fijarte que cuando defines el campo `ID_USUARIO` en la tabla `USUARIO` lo haces así:

```
ID_USUARIO BIGINT UNSIGNED not null auto_increment comment 'Id de la Tabla de Usuarios'
```

Sin embargo cuando defines al campo `ID_USUARIO` que servirá como foráneo en la tabla `CABECERA_VENTA` lo haces así:

```
ID_USUARIO Bigint not null comment 'Id del Usuario que realiza la compra'
```

Te darás cuenta que el primero los describes como `UNSIGNED` mientras que el ultimo no, debes entender que el campo foráneo debe ser del mismo tipo al de origen y por ello tu sentencia falla.

Answer (score 0):

en la tabla CABECERA_VENTA ya no uses ID_USUARIO, sino otro nombre ej. ID_US 
Y en donde hacer los constraints agrega 
FOREIGN KEY (ID_US) REFERENCES usuario(ID_USUARIO);
Y si harás modificaciones o eliminar algún detalle de la venta te recomiendo hacerlo en cascada ej.

FOREIGN KEY (ID_US) REFERENCES usuario(ID_USUARIO)
ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = #TU DB#

Espero y te sirva :)

Comment: El nombre del campo en la tabla CABECERA_VENTA no es ningún inconveniente, los campos foráneos de hecho suelen tener el mismo nombre que poseen en la tabla origen. Tu respuesta puede presentar confusión para iniciados en el tema.

Answer (score 0):

es por el valor *UNSIGNED* que tienes declarado en la tabla donde es primary key en la nueva tabla donde pasa a ser foranea tiene que tenes los mismos atributos